# postgres-14, COPY partition table running even after pg_dump has completed

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, pg-dump

Running into an issue running pg_dump with -Fd -Z 9 -j 10 using postgres-14 on linux. The backup completes from the cmdline, but I see that CREATE table IF not exists statements are blocked by a pid for pg_dump doing COPY of a partition table. Not quite sure why pg_dump is still running and doing COPY when pg_dump itself on cmdline completed successfully.

pg_dump completes successfully and no other job running related to pg_dump blocking other jobs

Comment: 1) Where are seeing this `... CREATE table IF not exists statements are blocked by a pid for pg_dump doing COPY of a partition table.`? 2) To your question add the query you used and the result.

Comment: It might be worth to try ```SELECT pg_terminate_backend(<put the PID here>);```, but only if you are really sure this should no longer be running

Comment: @AdrianKlaver CREATE table if not exists shows up when doing select to find the blocked pids in pg_stat_activity.  Then I just look up what the PID is using select * from pg_stat_activity  pid=blockingpid

Comment: @Islingre yeah that's what i did

Comment: How are you are determining something is blocked?

Comment: You must be mistaken, but you provide too little information to help.